# Why is `std::ptr::null` not usable with unsized types?

Tags: pointers, rust

As I understand, the standard (only?) way to make a null pointer in Rust is `std::ptr::null`.

However, that function is declared as follows.

```
pub const fn null<T>() -> *const T
```

In this declaration, `T` is implicitly assumed to have fixed size (otherwise, it would be `T: ?Sized`). As a consequence, it is impossible to use this function with `*const str` or `*const [u32]` for example. [test it in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=20969b6f4d8d1b2b6bdf7d96ac223b13)

Is there a good reason for excluding unsized types? What's wrong with wanting to create a null `*const str`?

Answer (score 8):

A pointer to an unsized type is a fat pointer with two components: the pointer and the type metadata (a length for slices, and a vtable pointer for trait objects; in the future, Rust may allow other kinds of metadata). `null` only implies a value for the pointer part; there's no obvious choice for the other value. (You might think 0 is obvious for the length of a null slice pointer, and I can see the argument, but if the pointer is null it hardly matters how many things are there; you can't dereference it anyway, so making the size 0 is not necessary to ensure safety.)

There is no way to create a null pointer to a trait object, but as of Rust 1.42, you can use [`ptr::slice_from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ptr/fn.slice_from_raw_parts.html) to create a null pointer to a slice. Let's suppose the length of the slice is 0:

```
use std::ptr;
fn main() {
    let p: *const [u32] = ptr::slice_from_raw_parts(ptr::null(), 0);
    println!("{:?}", p);
}
```

There is no equivalent function for `str`, but you could make one by creating a null `*const [u8]` and casting it with `as`.

This function (or the related `slice_from_raw_parts_mut`) is the only way to soundly create a null pointer to a slice. The usual way to get a raw pointer is by casting a reference, but references may never be null.

Comment: It's interesting that the `slice_from_raw_parts` is safe -- the reason being it's nigh unusable, as functions take a reference, not pointer, and `unsafe` is required to go from pointer to reference.

Comment: What would be the problem with a null fat pointer? You write that "there is no obvious choice for the [size]", but on the contrary, I would say that there is no *wrong* value for size, since the size does not matter for a null pointer...

Comment: @matthieu-m agreed, `slice_from_raw_parts` may produce a "wrong" `*const [T]` from a "good" `*const T` if provided with the wrong size, so I think it should be marked unsafe...

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine: Actually, I was agreeing with NOT marking it `unsafe`. Yes, it can produce a wrong `*const [T]` from a good `*const T`... but you cannot use that `*const [T]` without `unsafe` to transmute it to a `&[T]` or `&mut [T]`.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine Since there is no wrong length, what length should `null` return? Zero? One? Something arbitrary? Providing metadata suggests some intent to dereference the pointer, which is obviously wrong, so I submit that a null slice pointer (or a null trait object pointer) is probably the consequence of a design error. You should probably have an `Option<&[T]>` instead of a `*const [T]`, anyway.

Comment: @trentcl &-references are not an option for me because I can't assign a lifetime to them (otherwise, I wouldn't be using pointers, obviously). However, Option<NonNull<[T]>> does the trick...

Comment: I see absolutely zero harm or surprise in just using length zero. I just had the compiler stop me from doing the obvious thing I do with every other type and had to google and find this answer so I could be protected from what exactly? It's also completely reasonable to want a pointer to a slice, just like it's completely reasonable to have a pointer to an array in C, and it's completely reasonable to want to initialize a pointer to null. I'm already using pointers and expecting that I need to use the unsafe key word to dereference them, and I don't see marginal safety improvement here.