# Raw pointer to Trait in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, traits

How can I initialize a raw pointer to a trait?

Seems like I can not with null() nor null_mut().

Thanks.

```
trait State {}

struct Warrior {
  state: *mut dyn State
}

impl Warrior {
  fn new() -> Self {
    Self { state: null_mut() } // cannot infer type for type parameter `T` 
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot. See [Why is \`std::ptr::null\` not usable with unsized types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59426821/why-is-stdptrnull-not-usable-with-unsized-types) Why would you want to, though? It's impossible to populate the vtable pointer with anything meaningful, and you wouldn't be able to call any of the trait methods, anyway.

Comment: Long answer, I'm trying to apply (just to learn  a little more about rust) the State pattern and I need two mutable reference to the same object. Since it can not be done with safe rust then I'm trying with unsafe but I also need it to work with polymorphism (there should be more states) so I'm trying my luck with traits.

Comment: If you are trying to learn Rust, then you should follow the basic paradigm :-).  Namely, 1) do not ever have multiple mutable references to the same memory AND 2) do not attempt to use null pointers.  If you want to learn how to do those things, study c or c++ or assembler.  A little knowledge is a dangerous thing.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but I know already C/C++ and assambler which is why I am so interested in Rust. Saying "do not ever have multiple mutable references to the same memory" really makes you a bad programmer in my opinion. You can not avoid some problem in real life applications so there should be, even if it ugly, a way to solve it.

Comment: `&mut` references are unique by definition. They are like `restrict` pointers in C. There are still ways to use mutability through shared (`&`) references, most of which are supported by a safe abstraction in Rust's standard library: `Cell`, `Mutex`, `Rc`, the `Atomic` types, etc. If none of those satisfy your requirements, it's hard to imagine what you might want, but you may still be able to build it using `Option<NonNull<dyn State>>`, which is a valid target for unsized coercion and can be initialized to `None` without having to bother with pointer metadata.

Comment: _"Saying "do not ever have multiple mutable references to the same memory" really makes you a bad programmer in my opinion."_ -- having multiple mutable references to the same memory is **Undefined Behaviour** in Rust, so I would respectfully disagree.